# javascript - Reduce huge array list to make it more readable

Tags: javascript

I have a huge array with  list of variables going from 1 to 90 and it's really dirty and makes the js file little redable.

How can I clean it/factorize ? I tried some ways but it did not work. It's important to understand that below, all the i18nrotatingKw11/2... are not strings, they're variables.

```
const rotatingKwsListArr = [i18nrotatingKw1,i18nrotatingKw2,i18nrotatingKw3,i18nrotatingKw4,i18nrotatingKw5,i18nrotatingKw6,i18nrotatingKw7,i18nrotatingKw8,i18nrotatingKw9,i18nrotatingKw10,i18nrotatingKw11,i18nrotatingKw12,i18nrotatingKw13,i18nrotatingKw14,i18nrotatingKw15,i18nrotatingKw16,i18nrotatingKw17,i18nrotatingKw18,i18nrotatingKw19,i18nrotatingKw20,i18nrotatingKw21,i18nrotatingKw22,i18nrotatingKw23,i18nrotatingKw24,i18nrotatingKw25,i18nrotatingKw26,i18nrotatingKw27,i18nrotatingKw28,i18nrotatingKw29,i18nrotatingKw30,i18nrotatingKw31,i18nrotatingKw32,i18nrotatingKw33,i18nrotatingKw34,i18nrotatingKw35,i18nrotatingKw36,i18nrotatingKw37,i18nrotatingKw38,i18nrotatingKw39,i18nrotatingKw40,i18nrotatingKw41,i18nrotatingKw42,i18nrotatingKw43,i18nrotatingKw44,i18nrotatingKw45,i18nrotatingKw46,i18nrotatingKw47,i18nrotatingKw48,i18nrotatingKw49,i18nrotatingKw50,i18nrotatingKw51,i18nrotatingKw52,i18nrotatingKw53,i18nrotatingKw54,i18nrotatingKw55,i18nrotatingKw56,i18nrotatingKw57,i18nrotatingKw58,i18nrotatingKw59,i18nrotatingKw60,i18nrotatingKw61,i18nrotatingKw62,i18nrotatingKw63,i18nrotatingKw64,i18nrotatingKw65,i18nrotatingKw66,i18nrotatingKw67,i18nrotatingKw68,i18nrotatingKw69,i18nrotatingKw70,i18nrotatingKw71,i18nrotatingKw72,i18nrotatingKw73,i18nrotatingKw74,i18nrotatingKw75,i18nrotatingKw76,i18nrotatingKw77,i18nrotatingKw78,i18nrotatingKw79,i18nrotatingKw80,i18nrotatingKw81,i18nrotatingKw82,i18nrotatingKw83,i18nrotatingKw84,i18nrotatingKw85,i18nrotatingKw86,i18nrotatingKw87,i18nrotatingKw88,i18nrotatingKw89,i18nrotatingKw90];
```

Comment: If you are declaring these variables with `var` you can make it better.

Comment: If they're not strings, then there's not enough information to know what to do with it. Post how those variables are defined? (I'd use an array to start with, instead of creating `rotatingKwsListArr` later)

Comment: @MaheerAli yes somewhere in another file i have var i18nrotatingKw1 = "lorem"; var i18nrotatingKw2 ="ipsum"

Comment: @CertainPerformance they're just strings, think of it as cities name for example in a huge list i have

Comment: But you explicitly said `It's important to understand that below, all the i18nrotatingKw11/2... are not strings, they're variables.`

Comment: ho sorry th'eyre variables, but the VALUE of the variable is a string

Comment: ex: var i18nrotatingKw1 = "london";

Comment: Just declare those as an array instead, from the beginning, `const rotatingKwsListArr = ['london', ...` (note that arrays are zero-indexed, not one-indexed)

Comment: @CertainPerformance well they're in another file, so i can access them with the name i18nrotatingKw1/2/3... but i'd like to find a way not to have to create this huge list on 10 lines...like a loop

Comment: Sounds like you might change that other file to initialize an array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the variables declared with `var` in global scope are present in `window` object. You can access them using [**Bracket Notation**.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) Below is example with 3 variables

```js
var i18nrotatingKw1 ="something 1";
var i18nrotatingKw2 = "something 2"
var i18nrotatingKw3 = "something 3"

let arr = Array(3).fill().map((x,i)=>window[`i18nrotatingKw${i+1}`])
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: @Mathieu you are welcome. But I am curious why you didn't made an array initially containing those variables.

Comment: complicated: the gist of it is that i have some script that loop inside an array to show rotating words. these words are dependent on language of the page and they're all defined not on the same js file but on a i18n file so that's why...

Comment: if you're interested the other bit of the story is also having issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54786184/node-js-ejs-using-interpolation-inside-a-ejs-file-with-a-loop I tried to implement your interpolation brackets inside the ejs file but with no success

Comment: @Mathieu  sorry I am not familiar with ejs

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can't simply store the values of i18nrotatingKw1/... in an array to begin with, or declare them as properties of an object, remember that variables declared with `var` are hoisted to the variable object of the execution context. For example if you have in a JavaScript document:

```
var test1 = 'first'
var test2 = 'second'
```

then

```
console.log(this['test1'])
```

results in logging 'first'
You can use this to iterate over the number postfix in your variable names.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround solution is using `eval()`

For instance:

```
var evalString = 'const rotatingKwsListArr = ['

for (var i = 1; i <= 91; i++) {
  evalString += 'i18nrotatingKw' + i + ','
}

evalString = evalString.slice(0, -1) + '];'

eval(evalString)
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval): The `eval()` function evaluates JavaScript code represented as a string.