# Node.js/ejs - Using interpolation inside a ejs file with a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have an inline (in the html/ejs) script inside a ejs file and the file is built by node.

homepage.ejs

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script>
      var i18nRotatingKws = [];
      for (var i=1; i<90; i++) { 
        var i18nRotatingKws[i] = "<%- `rotatingKws.rotatingKw${i}` %>";
      } 
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

The output, after the ejs file is compiled should be:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script>
      var i18nRotatingKws = [];          
      var i18nRotatingKws[1] = "<%- rotatingKws.rotatingKw1 %>";
      var i18nRotatingKws[2] = "<%- rotatingKws.rotatingKw2 %>";
      var i18nRotatingKws[3] = "<%- rotatingKws.rotatingKw3 %>";
      var i18nRotatingKws[4] = "<%- rotatingKws.rotatingKw4 %>";
     //and so on until 90
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

Those values, rotatingKws.rotatingKw1, rotatingKws.rotatingKw2...are all defined then in a i18n file (dependent on the language).

I i don't use any loop in the ejs it's perfectly working. It means if I really write 90 lines such as `var i18nRotatingKws[1] = "<%- rotatingKws.rotatingKw1` %>";`the build works and I checked on the web page, it works too.

I have a special node.js script that parses the ejs file before tje ejs compiles to change the values from a i18n file like here:

i18n/locales.js

```
module.exports = {    
  rotatingKws: {
    rotatingKw1: __("rotatingKw1"),
    rotatingKw2: __("rotatingKw2"), 
    rotatingKw3: __("rotatingKw3"),
  },
}
```

locales/fr.js

```
module.exports = {  
  //rotatingKws
  "rotatingKw1":"nice keyword1",
  "rotatingKw2":"cool stuff",
  "rotatingKw3":"hip man",
}
```

The loop is the problem: the build fails and I get the following error:

```
i is not defined at eval
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You have the order wrong. First, ejs is processing everything `<% ... %>` (and can't find the `i`). The result is sent to the browser, and only then does the browser run the loop. If you want the loop to run on the server, you need to use an ejs loop.

Comment: @ChrisG i see, then is what I try to accomplish possible given this fact ?

Comment: i could put the for loop inside the <% %> ?

Comment: As far as I can tell you want to send an array to the client. What kind of data do you have in `rotatingKws.rotatingKw1`? Strings?

Comment: that's the key, i have set up a very specific system where this is parsed BEFORE the ejs compliation so that it goes to interpolate this and goes to fetch in my i18n file the value of the key. for example rotatingKws.rotatingKw1 is inside my locales file. I'll add now in the question this

Comment: I'm asking because this question seems to be an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). As far as I can tell you want `i18nRotatingKws` on the client to contain 90 strings the server loads from a locale file. Why not use AJAX and load the locale file directly from the client-side instead?

Comment: I did this for very specific reasons related to multiple context, language and domains...hard to go into details but it's working when I dont have this loop...as i said if i really write down the 90 lines and all have matching keys inside my i18n files, it works.

Comment: i want them on user load, not via ajax dynamically for technical reasons and seo reasons too.

Comment: If you have a script that preprocesses the ejs template, why doesn't it directly insert the `i18n` texts into the template?

Comment: I think that's what it does: it pre-process the ejs template and just replace all the values where it sees a <% %>

Comment: Ok, but in that case you *must* have all 90 `<%- ... %>` tags in the template. How else would the preprocessor be able to replace them with the actual texts?

Comment: i have them all the 90 in specific/organized files : for example, it first sees in the ejs file "<%- rotatingKws.rotatingKw1` %>";, so it goes on locales.js find if this key exist, then it find it and sees rotatingKws: {     rotatingKw1: __("rotatingKw1"), } so it goes to fetch the right language file for ex locales/fr.js and gets the value of rotatingKw1.

Comment: it's very specific i'm sorry ...

Comment: to be clear, if i directly write in my ejs files 90 lines like 
      var i18nRotatingKws[7] = "<%- rotatingKws.rotatingKw7 %>";, it works; but i'd like to "factorize", wirte thius more cleanly because my file the gets unreadable

Comment: Yes. And given how your system is set up, having those 90 lines is the *only way*.

Comment: might be...shit , thanks

Comment: can you not change your `i18n/locales.js` file instead of using an object to use an array?

Comment: You can always change your system though. There's no need to preprocess ejs files, given that ejs's main purpose is *inserting data into HTML*, which is exactly what you're trying to do. All you need to do is pass the proper locale file to your `res.render()` and directly insert the appropriate texts.

Comment: hehe you're right, but to be honest, I can't remember why I had to do this hackish way, but there was a major block at the time which led me to this complication...

Comment: thanks for all the advices.

Comment: If you want to take a look, I implemented my own version here: https://github.com/khrismuc/express-i18n relevant code is mostly in app.js, starting on line 30.

Comment: I'll gladly check it thanks a lot!